# codec/container with additional reconstruction information for archival?

Tags: encoding, codec

Are there (open source) codecs that support additional recovery information to be added during encoding to allow for an improved recovery from corruption?

Application would be data archival of videos - thus a somewhat overhead of ~10% is acceptable to be allow for a better error handling.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, [error correcting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code) (ECC) is added to the storage mechanism as with [Reed-Solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) on DVD and Blu-ray and the modifications for [forward error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) in [DVB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Video_Broadcasting#Transmission) and [ATSC](https://www.tvtechnology.com/expertise/error-correction-in-atsc-mobile-dtv) transports. Another common video archival medium, LTO tape, has [two levels of ECC](http://www.fujitsu.com/global/products/computing/storage/tape/eternus-lt/feature/STRSYS_a01.html). Building ECC into the codec would be redundant and wasteful, so they mostly focus on [error concealment](https://books.google.com/books?id=8jxbbRKVbkIC&lpg=PA251&ots=bel75kJtH-&dq=video%20codec%20ecc&pg=PA251#v=onepage&q=video%20codec%20ecc&f=false).